# How to grep lines with specific words, starting either with multiple spaces or tabs?

Tags: regex, grep, solaris, ksh

these are possible use cases, different samples of line from a file. These lines would be containing only one checkWord.

```
> checkWord
>     checkWord
>    checkWord
> <tab>   <tab> checkWord
> <tab>checkWord
> checkWord<tab>

how to grep all such cases?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` using:

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]*checkWord'
```

`^[[:blank:]]*` matches 0 or more space or tab characters at the start of line.

Comment: Isn't `[[:blank:]]` a non-POSIX GNU extension?

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is POSIX.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05  Seems a bit too *easily useful* to be POSIX, though.